# Query individual values in a nested json record

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, nested

I have the following table in Aurora Postgres:

```sql
create table newtable(column1 jsonb);

insert into newtable(column1) values 
('{"usertype":[{"type":"staff","status":"active","permissions": {"1": "add user","2": "add account"}}
             , {"type":"customer","status":"suspended"}
             , {"type":"corporate","status":"active"}]}');
```

I can get to a certain degree of data selection using the `LATERAL` query syntax. But I need help with querying one level deeper.

PLEASE Ignore: the additional rows selected as I tried a few formats.

```sql
SELECT json_line_item ->> 'type' as "type", json_line_item ->> 'status' as "status" , json_line_item->>'permissions'  "permissions"
FROM   newtable
,  LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(newtable.column1 -> 'usertype') json_line_item;
```

I want the permissions column as a list without any extra double quotes.

Another option is to get one single permissions by filtering (for eg: `permissions[1]` or `permissions[2]` etc.

Comment: [So do you have your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169168)

Answer (score 1):

#### List

> I want the permissions column as a list without any extra double quotes.

Use [`jsonb_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in another `LATERAL` subquery to extract (key and) object values, then concatenate the list with `string_agg()`:

```sql
SELECT id
     , js_line_item ->> 'type'        AS type
     , js_line_item ->> 'status'      AS status
     , js_line_item ->> 'permissions' AS permissions
     , p.permission_list                                -- !
FROM   newtable n
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(n.column1 -> 'usertype') AS js_line_item ON true
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(value, ', ') AS permission_list
   FROM   jsonb_each_text(js_line_item -> 'permissions')
   ) p;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2140a19f9da7c17864ddacb830086f6f)*

Use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` to retain all rows even without "usertype" data. I added an `id` to make that clearer. `CROSS JOIN` like before would eliminate such rows from the result.

The added table expression can be joined with a `CROSS JOIN` because a subquery with an aggregate function and no `GROUP BY` *always* returns a single aggregated row.

#### Single permissions

> ... get one single permissions by filtering (for eg: permissions[1] or permissions[2] etc.

```sql
SELECT id
     , js_line_item ->> 'type'   AS type
     , js_line_item ->> 'status' AS status
     , js_line_item -> 'permissions' ->> '1' AS permission_1  -- !
     , js_line_item #>> '{permissions, 2}'   AS permission_2  -- !
--   , js_line_item['permissions']['3']      AS permission_3  -- ! ① for pg 14
FROM   newtable n
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(n.column1 -> 'usertype') AS js_line_item ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2140a19f9da7c17864ddacb830086f6f)*

In (current) Postgres 13 you cannot iterate through objects of a *record* with subscripts like <strike>`permissions[1]`</strike>. That only works for *arrays*.

I added two syntax variants for Postgres 13.

① The third syntax variant requires **Postgres 14**, using the new ["`jsonb` subscripting"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING).
Use quoted key names to extract values from *objects*, and ordinal integer positions (starting at 0) to extract elements from *arrays*.
`3` in our example `js_line_item['permissions']['3']` is a key name and has to be quoted.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING)

> If a `jsonb` value is an array, numeric subscripts start at zero, and negative integers count backwards from the last element of the array. Slice expressions are not supported.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going through the code to understand but this is what I was looking for. It was very helpful.

Comment: One question. the single permissions show the permissions as one-per-column. One question. If this list is varying (i.e., type-staff,status-active, I have 2, but for a different type, status combination it could be more. How can I list each permission one per column though the list is varying?

Comment: @tenettestuser1: I suggest you ask a new question about this. My answer here is already too quite long.

Comment: posted a new question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68787797/how-to-query-a-nested-json-with-varying-key-value-pairs