# How to query a nested json with varying key value pairs

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My previous question has been answered, thanks to @Erwin Brandstetter for the help:

[Query individual values in a nested json record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784324/query-individual-values-in-a-nested-json-record)

I have a follow-up:

Aurora Postgres - PostgreSQL 13.1. My `jsonb` column value looks like this:

```
'{
    "usertype": [
        {
            "type": "staff",
            "status": "active",
            "permissions": {
                "1": "add user",
                "2": "add account"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "customer",
            "status": "suspended",
            "permissions": {
                "1": "add",
                "2": "edit",
                "3": "view",
                "4": "all"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

I would like to produce a table style output where each permission item i shown as a column. It should show the value if not null else it will be NULL.

```
 type     | status    | perm1   | perm2      | perm3 | perm4 | perm5 | perm6
----------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------
 staff    | active    | adduser | addaccount | null  | null  | null  | null
 customer | suspended | add     | edit       | view  | all   | null  | null
```

In other words, I would like a way to find out the max permissions count and show that many column in the select query.

Comment: Please make it easy for the reader of this question and include a [example] also in *this* question even if the previous question of yours already had one.

Comment: What sticky bit said. Plus, you still didn't declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: Updated the original question with version and example details

Answer (score 0):

An SQL query has to return a *fixed* number of columns. The return type has to be known at call time (at the latest). Number, names and data types of columns in the returned row(s) are fixed by then. There is no way to get a truly dynamic number of result columns in SQL. You'd have to use two steps (two round trips to the DB server):

1. Determine the list or result columns.
2. Send a query to produce that result.

Notably, that leaves a time window for race conditions under concurrent write load.

Typically, it's simpler to just return an array or a list or a document type (like JSON) for a variable number of values. Or a set of rows.

If there is a low, well-known maximum of possible values, say 6, like in your added example, just over-provision:

```sql
SELECT id
     , js_line_item ->> 'type'   AS type
     , js_line_item ->> 'status' AS status
     , js_line_item #>> '{permissions, 1}' AS perm1
     , js_line_item #>> '{permissions, 2}' AS perm2
--   ,  ...
     , js_line_item #>> '{permissions, 6}' AS perm6
FROM   newtable n
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(n.column1 -> 'usertype') AS js_line_item ON true;
```

`LEFT JOIN` to retain rows without any permissions.